# iOS 12 OpenVPN connection dirt slow, what is a better configuration?

Tags: ios, openvpn, asus

I am able to successfully connect to my Asus Router's OpenVPN server however, I pretty much get 0 bandwidth and can never navigate the internet.

Sample config file:

```
remote foobar.net 1194
float
nobind
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
keepalive 15 60
compress
auth-user-pass
client
auth SHA256
cipher AES-256-CBC
remote-cert-tls server
auth-nocache
```

I tried adjusting the auth and cipher but that had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched over to the iOS app Passepartout for my OpenVPN connection. I was experiencing the same slowness as before on the official OpenVPN app.

When asking the developer of Passepartout about this issue, they linked me to the app's FAQ, https://passepartoutvpn.app/faq/.

At the time, they mentioned that they disabled compression through the app due to OpenVPN's VORACLE vulnerability, https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/VORACLE.

Because of that, my connection was not compatible. I proceeded to remove `compress` from my OpenVPN config and was able to receive a connection and my bandwidth did not seem restricted.

Just listing here what I did to correct my original issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running OpenVPN without `sndbuf 0` and `rcvbuf 0`? According to the manual, when you don't manually set them they're set to the OS' default.

If this doesn't change anything, I suggest running your config with `verb 3` added. The client and server seem to have some configuration mismatch and this should hopefully reveal it. If your router has server logs, it might help to check those as well.

Comment: I just modified the compression, disabled both on my router and removed compress from my config. That seemed to do the trick. Why would that be?

Comment: @reid Usually when the compression between the client and server mismatch, they will keep sending each other packets that the other one can't understand and they don't automatically disconnect.  It might've been something else, but that's the most likely scenario.